# What is the most pythonic way to pass kwargs in this function?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, keyword-argument

I want to create a shortcut function for creating a question object in my django tests.

I don't like to type something like `new_q(timedelta(minutes=1))` all the time and I want to write that timedelta only once and be able to pass it's arguments in a nice way to the `new_q` function.

Is there any pythonic one line solution to this in which I don't have to capture the kwargs to a variable and then create a timedelta object in a new line?

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils import timezone


def new_q(question_text = '', offset=timedelta(**kwargs)):
    time = timezone.now() + offset
    return Question.objects.create(question_text=question_text, pub_date=time)
```

usage:

```
test1 = new_q(minutes=1)
test2 = new_q('yo?', seconds=1)
test2 = new_q(question_text = 'maw?', hours=11)
test2 = new_q(question_text = 'maw?')
test2 = new_q('yo?')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def new_q(question_text = '', **kwargs):
    time = timezone.now() + timedelta(**kwargs)
    ...
```

This is still pretty concise: it mentions `kwargs` twice, but there's no `offset` or anything else extra.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to write here doesn't quite make sense:

```
def new_q(question_text = '', offset=timedelta(**kwargs)):
```

This creates a default value for `offset`, and that value is created by calling `timedelta(**kwargs)` on whatever happens to be in `kwargs` at the time the function is defined. (Which is probably nothing at all, so you get a `NameError`.)

What you want is something like this:

```
def new_q(question_text = '', offset=None, **kwargs):
    if offset is None:
        offset = timedelta(**kwargs)
```

Now you're calling `timedelta` when the function is called, rather than when it's defined, and using the value of `kwargs` passed into the function, rather than whatever value that variable has at function definition time.

You could of course add some error handling, so the `TypeError` you get for an unknown keyword argument mentions `new_q` instead of `timedelta`, and so that it's an error to specify both `offset` and `minutes`, and so on.

Also, if someone passes neither `offset` nor any other keyword arguments, this will create a `timedelta()`—which is an empty `timedelta` (0 seconds). Is that what you want?

Comment: @tgwtdt Do you want people to be able to pass `offset=myoffset` if they already have a `timedelta` around they want to use? If not, then just drop the `offset=None` and the `if` and just write `offset=timedelta(**kwargs)` in the function.

Comment: @tgwtdt are you ladybug?

Comment: @AlexHall Well, that's awkward

Comment: The important thing to take from this answer is that **default values are evaluated once and only once, at definition time**.